# Change for loop condition with respect to an external flag (cpp)

Tags: c++

I have a code block as following, where the inner `for` loop code remains the same but only the loop condition changes based on the `reverseFlag`. Is there a better way to code this without having to copy paste the content of the `for` loop twice ?

```
bool reverseFlag=false;

if (reverseFlag)
{
    for(int i = 1; i < TotalFrames; i++)
    {...}
}
else
{
    for(int i = TotalFrames-1; i >0; i--)
    {...}
}
```

Comment: Move the `if` inside the loop? (if you say performance is critical, be prepared to back it up with measurements)

Comment: The loops are different (different conditions) so I don't think so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in a single `for` loop, like this:

```
int from, to, step;
if (reverseFlag) {
    from = TotalFrames-1;
    to = -1;
    step = -1;
} else {
    from = 0;
    to = TotalFrames;
    step = 1;
}
for (int i = from ; i != to ; i+= step) {
    ...
}
```

A single conditional ahead of the loop prepares loop's parameters - i.e. its starting and ending values and the step, and then the loop uses these three values to iterate in the desired direction.

Comment: that works perfectly. had thought of a similar implementation but was stuck with the for loop condition. I dint think of != operator.

Comment: This is beautiful! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. You can:

- Use two loops but put the loop body in a separate function/object/lambda.. to avoid duplication.
- Use an increasing loop and calculate the real index within the loop:

  ```
  j = reverseFlag ? TotalFrames - i : i;
  ```
- Pre-calculate the loop conditions as @dasblinkenlight suggested.

Note that if you have a performance critical loop, some of these methods could hurt performance. If in doubt, check what your compiler does and measure the elapsed time.